# Extending Django's Generic Views

Tags: django, django-views

I'm writing my first app in Django, and I have a problem with the `create_object` Generic View; In my `urls.py`, I have:

```
(r'^new$', CreateView.as_view()),
```

The problem is that when the user submits the "new" form, I need to manipulate the data that will be saved to the database (I actually need to add the `user_id` foreign key); without Generic Views I used to write:

```
    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.user = request.user
        data.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```

in my view (notice `data.user=request.user`). I've searched Django docs but I can't find a way to do this (maybe by extending the `CreateView` class) - somewere in The Book there is only an example that overrides the `get_object` method of a `ListView` class to update a `last_accessed_date` field.

Comment: Here is the "Performing extra work" where they explains the get_object method could be overridden by extending the class [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#performing-extra-work)

Answer (score 21):

You can do this by overriding the `get_form` method:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CustomCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(CustomCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return form
```

**EDIT**: Nowadays I would override [`form_valid`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#form_valid) as per [Issac Kelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148188/400691):

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CustomCreateView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CustomCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to override the [`form_valid` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid).