# Working with Django's FormView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have django model:

```
class ProjectFile(models.Model):

    TYPES = (
        (1, "Public"),
        (2, "In Project"),
        (3, "Specific")
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPES)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name + " - " + self.project.name

    def is_downloadable(self, user):
        if self.file.project.type == 1:
            return True

        return False
```

and form:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectFile
        exclude = ['created_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'project']
```

My view class (FormView) is:

```
class UploadFileView(FormView):
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = "project/file_upload.html"
```

So, my question now is: How to add data to excluded fields in my `views.py` for `UploadFileForm`. For example, `created_by` needs to be equal to `request.user`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7147059/400691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is intended to create a `ProjectFile`, I would recommend you use a [`CreateView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/createview), and override the `form_valid` method.

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class UploadFileView(CreateView):
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'project/file_upload.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(UploadFileView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You could still override the same method even if you wish to use the [`FormView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/formview).